# Where can I get a replacement lens hood for my Sigma 28mm f1.8?

Tags: sigma, lens-hood, repair-parts

I have a lens (the Sigma 28mm F1.8 EX DG Aspherical Macro) but the lens hood is lost. Where can I buy a new one? Can I use any lens hood that fits my lens?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65300/do-lens-hoods-need-to-be-matched-to-focal-length

http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/66016/what-should-i-consider-when-buying-a-lens-hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part number of the lens hood for the Sigma 28mm F1.8 EX DG Aspherical Macro is LH825-03 and you can find it [here](http://www.sigma-imaging-uk.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=66_87&product_id=130). There are probably numerous retailers for it and you'll have to find one you like yourself.

Since the lens hood is designed especially for your lens, you can't use any lens hood that physically fits the lens. See [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26752/21986) for more information on that.

Comment: Thank you soo much!! So its the shape of the lense hood that's important?

Comment: No problem. Yes since the the sensor/film is not circular, there are certain directions in which the lens hood can protrude more without interfering with the image. This is the reason for the petal shaped lens hoods (see [http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/399/21986](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/399/21986))

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a really tight budget you can download a pattern and print it to make a hood for your lens out of stiff paper or thin cardboard. Just be sure not to resize anything when printing.

Here's the pattern for the [Sigma 28mm f/1.8 EX DG](http://www.lenshoods.co.uk/hoods/Sigma-28mm-f-1.8-EX-DG.php) when used on a full frame body. If you are using an APS-C crop body, try [this one](http://www.lenshoods.net/hoods/Digital-Lenshood-Sigma-24mm-f-1.8-EX-DG.php).